# Pharo FileSystem: setUp of SUnit test which uses a file

Tags: file, smalltalk, pharo

I want to write a SUnit test which uses a file with the Pharo 4.0 FileSystem.
I want to write a file and then later read it.

Something like this

`fname := 'TabularTestExport1.xlsx'.
  (FileLocator temp / fname ) delete.
  TabularXSLXExport workbook: myWorkbook fileName: (FileLocator temp / fname ).`

### Questions

1. **temp directory** What is the method to use for using a temporary file in a platform independant way. `FileLocator temp` or `FileLocator tempDirectory` is not implemented.
2. **deleting an existing test file** How do I ensure that a file is deleted? I.e. How do I avoid a walkback in case the file does not exist.
3. Alternatively everything could be done in the memory: 1. creation of test file, 2. exporting test file, 3. Importing test file back

Comment: I like the FileLocator temp thing! I implemented something like that on my own several times e.g. http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~SeanDeNigris/SeansPlayground/packages/Tempfile

Answer (score 8):

For tests, unless you have a real big archive, is better to do things in memory. 
FileSystem provides you a way to do it, you just need to do:

```
fs := FileSystem memory.
```

It will give you a compatible API so you can make your tests. 
If you want a file and not a directory, you can do:

```
file := FileSystem memory / 'myFile'.
```

EDIT: I forget a couple of things:

1. `FileLocator temp` is implemented and should work fine for you. Why you say is not implemented? Are you not finding it for some reason, maybe?
2. `myFileReference ensureDelete` will... well, ensure your file is deleted :)